# Confusion with angular ChangeDetectionStategy.OnPush application to child components

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

According to [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` "applies to all child directives and cannot be overridden." As I understand, setting `OnPush` change detection for parent component is enough to skip child components' view updates until their `@Input` binding values not changed.

Below is example on stackblitz with the following component structure:

> app-component -> cmp1 -> cmp2 -> cmp3

Each of cmp* components display some value evaluated by `display` getter. App, cmp1 and cmp2 render buttons changing child component input values.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-detection-with-getters

When I set `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` **only** in `AppComponent` decorator, all three `display` getters are evaluated on every button click even if corresponding component inputs stay unchanged (open devtools console to see logs).

Desired behavior is reached only by setting `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` **for every component** (try to uncomment). That is

- changing cmp1's input triggers only cmp1 getter
- changing cmp2's input triggers cmp1 and cmp2 getters
- changing cmp3's input triggers cmp1, cmp2 and cmp3 getters

Why should I set OnPush change detection for every component to prevent child components to reevaluate getters? This is correct?

Comment: When using onPush change detection is still performed when:
a bound event is received on the component itself.
an @Input() was updated
| async pipe received an event
change detection was invoked "manually".
In your case it's the first the bounded event

Comment: The question is: why detection is perfotmed on lowest component in tree when action event is fired on the top most, i.e. click in app component changes input of cmp1, but display getters are executed in all components, including cmp3. And why setting OnPush on every component changes this behavior.

Comment: _click in app component changes input of cmp1, but display getters are executed in all components, including cmp3._ - I'm not observing that behavior. When `OnPush` is set for `cmp1`, and you click on `App`, only `display getter` is executed for `cmp1`.

Comment: @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard, execution of `display` getters probably was not clear because their results weren't changed. [On this fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-detection-with-getters-cmp1onpush) of example I've set `OnPush` only on `cmp1` and add to components field `num`, whick is incremented in getters and included in returninng result. Now you can see, that num of every component is changed on every button click.

Comment: @Egozavr, `OnPush` means that change detection won't run for a component if its inputs don't change. The fact that CD is not run for children is a side-effect, because CD is not run for a parent, it's not executed for children. But if you have CD executed for a parent, it will run for it's children, unless they are also OnPush. Read [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

Comment: Ah, thanks @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard, it's clear now.

Comment: So it's actually the documentation that is not correct here, right? I would think that 
**This strategy applies to all child directives and cannot be overridden** means all the children will have `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` set, which they clearly don't. Is that right?

Comment: @DawidZbiński: Yes exactly.